# AngularJS $log.debug is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging

I'm a bit frustrated because I can't figure out whats up with the AngularJS `$log` service. I don't use it often but I have it working on another part of my site, the only reason I could think it wouldn't be working would be something to do with the block scope inside the `then` function. 
 In my console I get the following error when trying to run `$log.debug`:

```
TypeError: $log.debug is not a function
    at analysis.client.controller.js:23
    at processQueue (angular.js:14551)
    at angular.js:14567
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15830)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15641)
    at angular.js:15869
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5387)
    at angular.js:5659
```

Heres my analysis.client.controller.js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('analysis').controller('AnalysisController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$mdSidenav', '$mdComponentRegistry', '$log', 'Authentication',
    function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdComponentRegistry, $log, Authentication) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;

        // Option #1
        //
        // $scope.isOpen = function() { return $mdSidenav('right').isOpen(); };
        // $scope.toggle = function() { $mdSidenav('right').toggle() };


        // Option #2 - See https://github.com/angular/material/issues/974

        $scope.toggle = angular.noop;
        $scope.isOpen = function() {
            return false;
        };

        $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
            $mdSidenav('left').toggle()
                .then(function() {
                    $log.debug('toggle left is done');
                });
        };
    }

]);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debug method is not enabled by default because not all browsers support `console.debug`, but you can enable it in the configuration phase of your app with the `$logProvider`.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('analysis')
  .config(function($logProvider){
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
  })
  .controller('AnalysisController', function(
    $scope,
    $timeout,
    $mdSidenav,
    $mdComponentRegistry,
    $log,
    Authentication
  ) {
    $scope.user = Authentication.user;

    // Option #1
    //
    // $scope.isOpen = function() { return $mdSidenav('right').isOpen(); };
    // $scope.toggle = function() { $mdSidenav('right').toggle() };


    // Option #2 - See https://github.com/angular/material/issues/974

    $scope.toggle = angular.noop;
    $scope.isOpen = function() {
      return false;
    };

    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
      $mdSidenav('left').toggle().then(function() {
        $log.debug('toggle left is done');
      });
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

`$log`'s `debug` method is disabled by default. You need to enable `$log` from app config phase like below.

```
app.config(function($logProvider){
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

Comment: `$log` by default it's enabled .  i tried accessing `.debug` with no config setting initially , its works as expected .

Answer (score -1):

FYI, I got this same error when I inadvertently reassigned the debug method instead of calling it.

```
$log.debug = 'My log message'
```

Instead of:

```
$log.debug('My log message')
```

After browsing to the page that had the bad statement, I would get `"TypeError: $log.debug is not a function"` on my other pages that had log statements.